# Annoying blinking light on printer M553

Tags: printer, switch

I have a Hewlett-Packard [M553 laser printer](http://www.imagetec.com.au/wp-content/uploads/HP-LaserJet-Enterprise-Colour-M553-Printer.pdf). This printer has a lighted power button on the front. The printer is on my desk. When the printer is in standby mode, which is 99.999% of the time, this light blinks constantly. Obviously this is insanely annoying to have a blinking light in my field of vision.

I have temporarily solved the problem by taping a piece of heavy cardboard over the switch. Is there any way to disable the blinking electronically?

Comment: Nope. It behaves that way so you can tell the difference between on, off, and standby.

Comment: Black insulating tape, camera or gaffa tape. Yep, it's a total pita, especially when you walk past the room at night & it's still flashing away. I've found no way to stop it :/

Comment: Have you tried checking the service mode options? The m553 pin is "4055315". I'll see what I can find, but that's usually how you change firmware based gpios on printers like this in the nv_ram. But I guess it depends on the firmware etc.